# Property table in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an info-table (only 1 line)

Is there a way to read and update it in Rails without stuff like MyInfo.get(:all).first?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the answer you're looking for but you don't have to use `.get(:all)`

ActiveRecord provides the method `.first`

Replace: `MyInfo.get(:all).first` with `MyInfo.first`

This is a small simplification, but what I suggest is creating a method in `app/controllers/application_controller.rb` like so:

```
def app_info
  MyInfo.first
end
```

That way you can call it use it easily and modify it to add/exclude information in one place.